# How to properly filter and iterate in a view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift5

I'm using Swift 5, and have a struct model (Book: userId, category, title) , which is stored in Firedbase via Repository class, and accessed via a Book List view (which utilises Book Cell subviews).

Both BookList and Book Cell have View Models which I'm using for all data access in the view via an Observed Object and publishing from the VM.

In its simplest form, on init of the VM, I call the repository and get all Books for a certain userId and this works fine.

My goal is to be able to display sections / carousels for each book category. This is where I'm falling down and have got completely stuck (I'm sure it's simple too, which is frustrating :))

1. f I've got the full collection in the View Model instance already, so I think it should be a case of filtering that and foreaching across the result, but whatever I try doesn't work.

As an example, here's what I think "should maybe" work? / is as close as I've got to something which will compile, but ultimately not work... (I've tried a number of other things, and the compiler complains about the class not being Hashable, which I've gone down the rabbit hole on and didn't get anywhere either).

```
struct BookListView: View {
            @ObservedObject var bookListVM = BookListViewModel()

            var body: some View {
        ...

    // this doesn't work
    ForEach(bookListVM.bookCellViewModels.filter {$0.book.category == "XYZ TEST"}) { example in 
    let _ = print("DEBUG: \(example.book.heading)")
         } 

    // this does
    ForEach(bookListVM.bookCellViewModels) { bookcellVM in
        ...
}
```

2. Is there a better way to go about just getting a filtered result set from a call from the view to the VM -> Repository (rather than filter the entire set all the time)? I've tried a straight func call, which returns nothing and am struggling with why (suspect it's my lack of understanding of how the async stuff is working? Appreciate this part is a bit vague, but any pointers to something which explains this would be very much appreciated, I've googled everything I can think of!.

Hope that all makes sense, and thank you for any and all help and guidance!

Comment: Filtering is not the job of your view.  It is the job of your view model.  Provide the filtered list to `BookListView`,

Comment: Yep, that's the route I took initially, I was attempting to pass a custom dictionary to the view, but I can't iterate over that in the view either, so I'm at a bit of a loss?

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, update, I've switched to passing a custom struct and that works - still no idea why I can't filter the array in a view though...